# Magento Module SQL/Setup Resource File

Tags: sql, magento, module

I updated the SQL file for my module - how do i get it to automatically run again without creating a new version of it?

I am working on my first module and just need to tweak this one so it works on a new install for someone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When Magento automatically runs a SQL file for a setup resource, it makes an entry in the `core_resource` table.

```
mysql> SELECT code,version,data_version FROM core_resource;

adminnotification_setup     1.0.0   1.0.0
admin_setup                 0.7.2   0.7.2
amazonpayments_setup        0.1.2   0.1.2
api_setup                   0.8.1   0.8.1
backup_setup                0.7.0   0.7.0
bundle_setup                0.1.11  0.1.11
...
```

You'll need to remove the **single** row in this table that corresponds to your module, and then clear your Magento cache.  This will let you re-run your setup resource SQL file.

**ONLY** remove that single row — if you remove rows for the core modules, there will be much breaking and weeping.

Comment: I removed just that one line and it errored out. I only removed the 1 line. I also cleared the cache manually afterward.

Comment: I found it won't let me delete a row in the DB that was added to eav_entitiy_type.

So it keeps failing when it gets to adding that INSERT

Comment: @jordan I'm afraid I don't understand what you're saying.